# pfimageview size control

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

i use parse.com pfimageview, i want to control the image size every time i upload new image to it. here is my code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet PFImageView *imageku;
imageku.image  = [self squareImageWithImage:imageNormal scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];
imageku.layer.cornerRadius = imageku.frame.size.width / 2;
imageku.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

but i can not, because there is an error because this syntax unrecognise:

```
squareImageWithImage:imageNormal
```

i want to make that imageku stay on size 30x30 every time i uploaded new image, please help me.

i mean i upload new image to parse.com database, and when i called it from database, it is not shown as 30x30 image (default image), it is bigger than 30x30, so i need to control imageku to stay on 30x30.

Comment: show your method squareImageWithImage: content.

Comment: i use other answer from stackoverflow [self squareImageWithImage:imageNormal scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(30, 30)], so i think that line is wrong. i need better code to make imageku to stay on 30x30 (icon size thumbnail). thank you for answer mr.dheeraj.